# case condition then using two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
select firstname,lastname 
from table1 (nolock) 
left outer join table2 
    on table1.ID=table2.ID
where table1.billingaddress like 'Lake street''
```

Am trying to use like when table1.billingaddress isnull i need to replace that with

table2.shippingaddress

```
select firstname,lastname 
from table1 (nolock) 
left outer join table2 
    on table1.ID=table2.ID
where case billingaddress isnull then shippingaddress like 'Lake street'
```

I am not getting desired result and please share your thoughts how to implement this using sql query.

Comment: Are you essentially trying to do `WHEN billingaddress IS NULL THEN shippingaddress LIKE 'Lake Street' ELSE billingaddress LIKE 'Lake Street'`?

Comment: so `WHERE billingaddress IS NOT NULL OR (billingaddress IS NULL AND shippingaddress LIKE 'Lake street')'`?

Comment: This query will be executed under a if loop which will have if address is equal to billingaddress). For some extreme cases instead of displaying null/empty, am trying to display shipping address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select firstname,lastname 
from table1 (nolock) 
left outer join table2 on table1.ID=table2.ID
where isnull(billingaddress, shippingaddress) like 'Lake street'
```

Answer (score 1):

From Comments: When the billing address is null, this checks if the shipping address is like lake street, and will return all rows with a non null billing address, and those where it is null if the shipping address is like 'Lake street'

```
SELECT firstname,lastname 
FROM table1 (nolock) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 on table1.ID=table2.ID
WHERE billingaddress IS NOT NULL OR (billingaddress IS NULL AND shippingaddress LIKE 'Lake street')
```

First attempt based on question alone:

This query will get anything where the billing address is like 'lake street', but if the billing address is null will get anything where the shipping address is like 'lake street'.

```
SELECT firstname,lastname 
FROM table1 (nolock) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 on table1.ID=table2.ID
WHERE COALESCE(billingaddress, shippingaddress) LIKE 'Lake street'
```

Edit: Like 'Lake street' is kind of pointless, please tell me you at least use a wildcard in there?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want, just so I can make this clear, is:

If Table1.billingaddress is not null, "LIKE billingaddress"

Else "LIKE shippingaddress"?

I'll edit this into an answer if I understand you correctly.

```
select firstname,lastname 
from table1 (nolock) 
left outer join table2 on table1.ID=table2.ID
where CASE WHEN billingAddress IS NULL THEN shippingAddress ELSE billingAddress END LIKE     'Whatever'
```

Comment: I can't add comments to others' answers.  jay c.'s is better/more obvious.